# Breaking up multiple words and inserting an image after first word

Tags: functions, loop

I'm not sure if it's possible, however, what I'm after is to break up WordPress titles that are multiple words and then insert an image.

My current loop works just fine. Right now it gets the page's featured image, then shows the page title:

```
<img>
WordPress Development
```

Here's the loop:

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $page_id->ID,
    'showposts' => $show,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$subpages = new WP_query($args);

if ($subpages->have_posts()) : while ($subpages->have_posts()) : $subpages->the_post();

    $output .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="'.$page_id->post_name.'-link"><div class="'.$page_id->post_name.'-info"><div class="'.$page_id->post_name.'-img">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID,'icons').'</div><h2>'.get_the_title().'</h2></div></a></li>';

endwhile; endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

return $output;
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is having the put more like this:

```
WordPress
<img>
Development
```

All of the page titles used in this loop with be 2 words. Any thoughts or suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know that there will always be two words separated by a space, you can use [explode](https://www.php.net/explode). Something like this:

```
$pieces = explode(" ", get_the_title());
$word1 = $pieces[0];
$word2 = $pieces[1];

$output .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="'.$page_id->post_name.'-link"><div class="'.$page_id->post_name.'-info"><h2>'.$word1.'</h2><div class="'.$page_id->post_name.'-img">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID,'icons').'</div><h2>'.$word2.'</h2></div></a></li>';
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfect. Out of curiosity, if I wanted to make this more dynamic and use with with titles that were longer than 2 words, is there a way to 'explode' the title in half?